# VS2019 Directory Context Menu in different language

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I right click in any folder or desktop the following directory context menu shows up, I don't know what language is it, so how do I change it to English? I have tried changing the language settings in the device as well as VS. Do let me know any information you need. Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools->Environment->international settings and set language as english
restart VS if problem still persist try restarting system if still problem persists
open Visual studio installer go to language packages and remove the languages apart from english

Comment: The last solution worked! The language packages were the problem. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is related to language packs you've installed with visual studio.

Run the Microsoft visual studio installer>Click on modify>On the "language packs" tab>Uncheck additional languages including Chinese>Hit modify.

Update: If the item on the windows context menu changed to "AnyCode" or some other weird things after removing additional language packs, you can change it manually from windows registry like [This](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-right-click-context-menu/).